# Get only parents having childs in cakephp associations

Tags: cakephp, associations

I have setup simple association like, an author has many books and a book belongs to an author.My files are as below.

```
<?php
class Author extends AppModel
{
   var $name = 'Author';
   var $hasMany = 'Book';
}
?>

<?php
class Book extends AppModel
{   var $name = 'Book';
    var $belongsTo = 'Author';
}
?>


<?php
class AuthorsController extends AppController {
   var $name = 'Authors';

   public function index(){
   $authors=$this->Author->find('all');
   pr($authors);die;
 }

}
?>
```

When i write pr($authors); it print all the data of the authors table.

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [Author] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 1
                    [name] => Jack
                    [email] => test@test.com
                    [website] => www.Jack.com
                )

            [Book] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 1
                            [isbn] => a12sdsdsd
                            [title] => Book One
                            [description] => Description One
                            [author_id] => 1
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 2
                            [isbn] => fgg234234
                            [title] => Book Two
                            [description] => Description Two
                            [author_id] => 1
                        )

                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [Author] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 2
                    [name] => Ron
                    [email] => demo@demo.com
                    [website] => www.Ron.com
                )

            [Book] => Array
                (
                )

        )

)
```

As you can see, author(Ron) having id:2 has no book. So the Book array is empty.What i want is to get only those authors having any book(here only author Jack data should be returned).How to achieve this?I have read about containable behaviour at:

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/behaviors/containable.html

But there is no such option to achieve this.Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue an this is the way I solved it, its dirty but I could not find a better solution in CakePhp 1.3

You could also try to do a $this->query with a having

```
//Inside model
        $authors = $this->find( 'all', array(
        'fields' => $fields,
        'conditions' => $conditions,
        'order' => 'id asc',
        'contain'=>array(
            'Book' => array(
                'conditions'=> $bookConditions,
                ),
            )
        )
    );

    //We don't want the results without books
    foreach($authors as $index => $author){
        if( ( !$author['Book'] ) ){
            unset($authors[$index]);
        }
    }

    return $authors;
```

Comment: This won't work with pagination and it's overall a pretty slow solution and won't lead to accurate results when expecting 10 but 6 of them get unset.

Answer (score 0):

Implement a [counter cache](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/associations-linking-models-together.html#countercache-cache-your-count) so that you get the number of books in the authors table you can then simply find by this condition (model code):

```
array($this->alias . '.book_count > 0');
```

The counter cache removes the need to have sub selects in SQL (slow) that will do the count or do filtering on the results which is slow and inaccurate.